# Deleted question by mistake

Tags: support

I posted [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27583/powershell-script-executing-within-sql-server-agent) yesterday - I seem to have deleted it by mistake.

Could you please reinstate it?

Thanks

Comment: Done :)...........

Comment: Hey @JackDouglas could you make your comment here an answer? That way this question doesn't look unanswered. :)

Comment: @Aarthi ok, but only if you can tell me whether Barry could have undeleted it himself–I wasn't sure ;-)

Comment: I did try to reinstate it by visiting the URL but I just received a nice message telling me I had deleted it. Viewing my questions page in my profile didn't display it either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done :)

I Wondered why you couldn't see the question to undelete it yourself. I found some answers on mSO:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101361/166851
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101368/166851
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/166851

Comment: now I wonder why only the first link shows the question title?

Comment: The other to are answer links. I think only question links get auto-prettified.

Comment: @Mat thanks, that explains it :)